# What exactly is Widevine? And how to ensure that I have this key on device?

Tags: java, android, encryption, drm, widevine

I'm working on a factory that will start to record Widevine Key on their device and I need to ensure that key is really there and working perfectly. Can't find any useful information about to retrieve data to confirm that key is working properly.

I don't know for sure what Widevine does, but I know that is something related to encrypt data for stream. Maybe there a way to test running any audio ou video from internet. Is this right? Could anyone show me a starting point?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so Widevine is a browser plugin that allows high quality video to be viewed securely (as in viewers can't easily steal it). I don't know what you mean by key? However, as with anything that runs in the browser you can inspect it using [chrome dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network) and viewing the network tab to see whats going on. I hope that helped.

Oh yeah, you could use something like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) or https://www.wireshark.org/ as well.

Comment: Ok, I will study a little more these tools. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Cool you should mark this question as answered so people other people can see it..

Comment: "viewers can't easily steal it" - I strongly disagree with your use of the term "steal". There are many legitimate and legal uses involving the appropriation of copyrighted content, Fair Use in the US, for example. We all need to understand and appreciate that while DRM has its job to make copyright violations harder, it *does* necessarily trample on consumer rights and harms the preservation and study of media.